# Laravel - Where is the list of migrations that were created?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Where is the file list of migrations that were created, executed, and so on?

I mean a list of files, for example, I created the migration, applied, and then deleted the file with it, and then tried to reset the changes, an error will be found, because such a file was not found and I want to know the file in which it is described which migrations were created ...

Comment: Changes are saved in `migrations` table if you ask for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are in the `/database/migrations` directory.

If you need the list of executed migrations, check migrations table in your database.

Or search your migrations in `/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I mean the file list, for example, I created the migration, applied and then deleted the file with it, and then tried to dump the changes, there will be an error, because such a file is not found, and I want to know this file in which describes which migrations were created ...

Comment: @Ostap34PHP Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete a `migration` and then do migrate again you should delete all the tables in your database or just the `migrations` table

Comment: Delete these files from the migrations table of your database.